# Crop and merge two images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to place one image (`Poseidon_map01.jpg` in my code below) in the top-left corner of another (`zzOcean Backdrop.png`) then crop the resulting image down to 1280x720.

This is the command I currently have:

```
".\ImageMagick-7.0.8-12-portable-Q16-x64\magick.exe" ".\Raw\zzOcean Backdrop.png" ".\Raw\Poseidon_map01.jpg" -gravity northwest -composite -crop 1280x720>! +repage ".\1280x720\Poseidon_map01.jpg"
```

The problem is that this command is cutting the composited image into 1280x720 pieces then saving all of those pieces with the names `Poseidon_map01-1.jpg` to `Poseidon_map01-48.jpg`. `Poseidon_map01-1.jpg` is the top-left corner of the composited image and this is the piece that I want to keep. I want to discard the rest of the composite. Does anyone know what I have to change in my command to make this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick crop, if you do not include the +X+Y offsets, it will crop as many pieces as it can given the size you specify. That is called tiled cropping. So use -crop WxH+X+Y>!

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

```
".\ImageMagick-7.0.8-12-portable-Q16-x64\magick.exe" ".\Raw\zzOcean Backdrop.png" ".\Raw\Poseidon_map01.jpg" -gravity northwest -composite -crop 1280x720+0+0>! +repage ".\1280x720\Poseidon_map01.jpg"
```

I am not a windows user and syntax may vary some. You may need to escape the > or ! with ^ on windows or put double quotes around the whole crop set of arguments. Keep that in mind, if this does not work. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I knew about those offsets but assumed they were for situations where you wanted your crop offset from the edge of the source image.

Comment: On Windows, you would need to escape the `>` sign as this, like Linux, is used to redirect output. In my case though, I'm using AutoHotkey to run this command and none of the characters used here need to be escaped.